# Using single quote in C# Process.Start argument

Tags: c#, linux, .net-core, process, parameter-passing

I'm need to execute Linux command line programs from .Net Core with arguments which include single quote `'`

Two examples:

```
dpkg-query -W -f=' ${db:Status-Status} ' mariadb*

virsh qemu-agent-command SRV01 '{"execute":"guest-ping"}'
```

In C#:

```
Process proc = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
ProcessStartInfo pi = new ProcessStartInfo("dpkg-query");
pi.Arguments = "-W -f=' ${db:Status-Status} ' mariadb*";
proc.StartInfo = pi;
proc.Start();
```

One example of error message: `'''''''''''''''''''dpkg-query: no packages found matching ${db:Status-Status} dpkg-query: no packages found matching '`

I'm calling perhaps 30 difference programs with arguments without any problems. Only have issue with the single quote

Also tried to use the `ProcessStartInfo.ArgumentList` and many basic escape tricks but with not success.

Comment: I think so...according to the dpkg-query manual, line 122: `syntax  “${field[;width]}”`

Comment: The debug value is `-W -f=' ${db:Status-Status} ' mariadb*`
I can see the error messages from the programs in the console.They execute fine in Linux shell

Comment: @ RobertBaron: It's called from a .Net Core console program running on Linux (with the .Net Core runtime installed).

Comment: @mjwills: The program is running as root and it doesn't matter which working folder I'm in. 
Additional info: All other commands without single quotes work fine

Comment: One example of error: `'''''''''''''''''''dpkg-query: no packages found matching ${db:Status-Status}
dpkg-query: no packages found matching '
`. But it all depend on the program and the arguments of course. Bottom line is something happens when the quotes get parse. I think it's some C++ parsing issue
As I said tried MANY different escape solutions.

Comment: @ RobertBaron: using that exact same code with argument without single quotes works fine.

Comment: As I written in the question: `Also tried to use the ProcessStartInfo.ArgumentList ......`;-)
Same issue with .Net core 3 by the way

Comment: Can you show us your attempt to use `ArgumentsList`?

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace Exe
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Process proc = new System.Diagnostics.Process();

            //In the Linux shell: dpkg-query -W -f=' ${db:Status-Status} ' mariadb*:
            ProcessStartInfo pi = new ProcessStartInfo("dpkg-query");
            pi.ArgumentList.Add("-W");
            pi.ArgumentList.Add("-f= ${db:Status-Status} ");
            pi.ArgumentList.Add("mariadb*");

            pi.UseShellExecute = false;
            proc.StartInfo = pi;
            proc.Start();
            do { System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(50); } while (proc.HasExited == false);
            Environment.Exit(0);
        }
    }
}
```

And another command example:

```
....
//In the Linux shell: virsh qemu-agent-command SRV04 '{"execute":"guest-ping"}'
ProcessStartInfo pi = new ProcessStartInfo("virsh");
pi.ArgumentList.Add("qemu-agent-command");
pi.ArgumentList.Add("SRV03");
pi.ArgumentList.Add("{\"execute\":\"guest-ping\"}");
....
```

Solved with help from [TSlivede](https://github.com/TSlivede) and [jnm2](https://github.com/jnm2) on the this [github.com](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/35222) tread :-)